# Fll an asset with colour

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, colors, sprite-kit

I have a variable `var image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image")` and it is an outline. I want to fill the image with colour but do not know the code necessary. Would someone be able to provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it, and wrapped in a `SpriteNode` extension for convenience:

```
extension SKSpriteNode {

  func fromFilledPath(path: CGPath, color: SKColor) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let shape = SKShapeNode(path: path)
    shape.fillColor = color
    return SKSpriteNode(texture: SKView().texture(from:shape))
  }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

  let myPathSprite = SKSpriteNode.fromFilledPath(~~~~)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a SKSpriteNode or an image.  What you need to do is create a path of the outline using `UIBezierPath` or `CGPath`,  and then creating a context designed to fill in the pathed area.

Then you can return the generated image and attach this to a sprite.

```
func fillInPath(path: CGPath, color: UIColor) -> UIImage?
{
    let size = path.boundingBoxOfPath()
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( size)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return nil
    } 
    context.addPath(path) // the path of your outline
    context.clip()
    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let image = UIImage(cgImage:context.makeImage()!)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image            
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this be easier / more performant to do as a skshape, then convert it to a sprite?

Comment: not sure which would be more efficient, but the context gives you more options to play with